# How to create a new list element i javascript without creating new ul-elements for each new item

Tags: javascript, list, task

I'm trying to create a tasklist in javascript. I want the user to be able to add new list items as tasks, but I cannot figure out how to do next...

So my problem is the following:

for each new input the user gives, instead of adding on li-element to the ul-element, new ul-elements keep creating containing only one li-element. How do I do to add li-elements to the same ul-element, without creating new ul-elements for each new task/input created?

**This is html and javascript code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="createNewTaskContainer">
<form id="taskForm">
<input id="taskInput" type="text" />
<button type="submit" id="createTaskButton">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="listOfTasksContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
let toDoList = [];
    
window.onload = function () {
let form = document.getElementById("taskForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", addTask); }
    
function insertTasksInHtml() {
let liElement = document.createElement("li");
let ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
    
ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
      document.getElementById("listOfTasksContainer").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("listOfTasksContainer").appendChild(ulElement);
console.log(ulElement);
    
for (let i = 0; i < toDoList.length; i++) {
liElement.innerText = toDoList[i];
}
}

function addTask(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    
let taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput").value; 
    
if (taskInput === "") {
alert("Please insert a task before you submit");
} else {
toDoList.push(taskInput);
insertTasksInHtml();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let toDoList = [];
    
window.onload = function () {

let ulElement;
let node;
let textnode;
let form = document.getElementById("taskForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", addTask); }
    
function insertTasksInHtml(newTask) {
  ulElement = document.getElementById("list");
  node = document.createElement("li");  
  textnode = document.createTextNode(newTask);     
  node.appendChild(textnode);    
  ulElement.appendChild(node);                   
}

function addTask(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  let taskInput = document.getElementById("taskInput").value; 
    
  if (taskInput === "") {
    alert("Please insert a task before you submit");
  } else {
    toDoList.push(taskInput);
    insertTasksInHtml(taskInput);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="createNewTaskContainer">
<form id="taskForm">
<input id="taskInput" type="text" />
<button type="submit" id="createTaskButton">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="listOfTasksContainer">
<ul id="list">

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `liElement` inside the loop and append to `Ul`.

```js
function insertTasksInHtml() {

   let ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
    
 document.getElementById("listOfTasksContainer").innerHTML = "UL";
 document.getElementById("listOfTasksContainer").appendChild(ulElement);
 //console.log(ulElement);
    
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   let liElement = document.createElement("li");
   liElement.innerText = 'LI ' + i;
   ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
 }
}

insertTasksInHtml();
```

```html
<div id="listOfTasksContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this now and I haven't bumped into any problems, so thank you!